# Запустить команду, и кликнуть на окно для его закрытия

Tags: linux

Подскажите команду в Linux. Где-то видел, запустив команду, можно нажать на окно, и приложение закроется. Может это сигнал какой, я просто не помню. Буду признателен, если поможете.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Скорее всего, Вы имеете в виду **xkill**.

> Xkill - это графический способ завершения приложений. Когда вы введете
>   "xkill" в терминале, курсор примет вид крестика. Все, что вам
>   требуется, кликнуть этим крестиком в окне нужного приложения и оно
>   немедленно завершится. Если вам понравится такой способ, можно
>   настроить для активации xkill горячие клавиши.

Comment: Вот, точно! ``xkill``! Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Добавлю, что часто он по дефолту замаплен на Ctrl+Alt+Esc.